# SyntaxError: Digit expected on hardhat-compile

Tags: hardhat

Here is a contract I am trying to compile

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


contract EscrowView is Ownable {
    uint public feePercent;
    address public feeAddress;

    enum PoolType {
        BUY,
        SELL
    }

    struct EscrowPool {
        PoolType pType;
        address poolCreator;
        address tokenAddr;
        uint amount;
        address[] exchangeTknsAddr;
        uint[] exchangeTknsAmount;
    }
    uint public noOfPools;
    mapping(uint => EscrowPool) public poolsTable;
    
}
```

This is file-name of my contract: `1.Escrow_view.sol`

Whenever I run `npx hardhat compile`, I get this error:

```bash
Generating typings for: 1 artifacts in dir: typechain-types for target: ethers-v5
An unexpected error occurred:

SyntaxError: Digit expected. (4:20)
  2 | /* tslint:disable */
  3 | /* eslint-disable */
> 4 | import type * as 1EscrowViewSol from './1.Escrow_view.sol';
    |                    ^
  5 | export type { 1EscrowViewSol };
  6 | import type * as escrowViewSol from './Escrow_view.sol';
  7 | export type { escrowViewSol };
    at k (/home/mahesh/web3werx/escrow/escrow_contracts/node_modules/prettier/parser-typescript.js:1:15163)
    at cT (/home/mahesh/web3werx/escrow/escrow_contracts/node_modules/prettier/parser-typescript.js:257:10765)
    at Object.uT [as parse] (/home/mahesh/web3werx/escrow/escrow_contracts/node_modules/prettier/parser-typescript.js:257:11074)
    at Object.parse (/home/mahesh/web3werx/escrow/escrow_contracts/node_modules/prettier/index.js:7331:23)
    at coreFormat (/home/mahesh/web3werx/escrow/escrow_contracts/node_modules/prettier/index.js:8645:18)
    at formatWithCursor2 (/home/mahesh/web3werx/escrow/escrow_contracts/node_modules/prettier/index.js:8837:18)
    at /home/mahesh/web3werx/escrow/escrow_contracts/node_modules/prettier/index.js:37832:12
    at Object.format (/home/mahesh/web3werx/escrow/escrow_contracts/node_modules/prettier/index.js:37846:12)
    at prettierOutputTransformer (/home/mahesh/web3werx/escrow/escrow_contracts/node_modules/typechain/src/codegen/outputTransformers/prettier.ts:8:19)
    at /home/mahesh/web3werx/escrow/escrow_contracts/node_modules/typechain/src/typechain/io.ts:22:33 {
  loc: { start: { line: 4, column: 20 } },
  codeFrame: '\x1B[0m \x1B[90m 2 |\x1B[39m \x1B[90m/* tslint:disable */\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n' +
    '\x1B[0m \x1B[90m 3 |\x1B[39m \x1B[90m/* eslint-disable */\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n' +
    "\x1B[0m\x1B[31m\x1B[1m>\x1B[22m\x1B[39m\x1B[90m 4 |\x1B[39m \x1B[36mimport\x1B[39m type \x1B[33m*\x1B[39m \x1B[36mas\x1B[39m \x1B[35m1\x1B[39m\x1B[33mEscrowViewSol\x1B[39m \x1B[36mfrom\x1B[39m \x1B[32m'./1.Escrow_view.sol'\x1B[39m\x1B[33m;\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n" +
    '\x1B[0m \x1B[90m   |\x1B[39m                    \x1B[31m\x1B[1m^\x1B[22m\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n' +
    '\x1B[0m \x1B[90m 5 |\x1B[39m \x1B[36mexport\x1B[39m type { \x1B[35m1\x1B[39m\x1B[33mEscrowViewSol\x1B[39m }\x1B[33m;\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n' +
    "\x1B[0m \x1B[90m 6 |\x1B[39m \x1B[36mimport\x1B[39m type \x1B[33m*\x1B[39m \x1B[36mas\x1B[39m escrowViewSol \x1B[36mfrom\x1B[39m \x1B[32m'./Escrow_view.sol'\x1B[39m\x1B[33m;\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n" +
    '\x1B[0m \x1B[90m 7 |\x1B[39m \x1B[36mexport\x1B[39m type { escrowViewSol }\x1B[33m;\x1B[39m\x1B[0m'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was gone when I renamed my contract file name from `1.Escrow_view` to `Escrow_view`

Don't know why this happens, as I named files like this many times before, looks like new version of hardhat using some standards from prettier.